# Validation not working on localhost server in VS2010 (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

i have upgraded from VS2008 to VS2010 and i am facing validation problem. previously in VS2008 all validations works perfectly but after upgrading to VS2010 , the validations(Required field validator,Regular expression validator, Custom validator etc) only works in IIS and donot work on localhost . Any suggestions??

Comment: By localhost you mean in IIS express? Can you show your html code, it usually needs some html attribute like required, are they still present.

Comment: By localhost i mean when i run my source code on my machine it dont work , and when i publish my code and host on IIS Manager, validation works perfectly .

Comment: Here is my Code  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="revTimein" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="txtTimefrom" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator"
                        ValidationExpression="(0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M)" 
                            SetFocusOnError="True">enter in a valid format hh:mm AM\PM</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>